# How do I create and read from arrays in Android?

Tags: android, arrays

I've used arrays in other languages (Python, MATLAB/Octave, C, Visual Basic, BASIC), but I haven't figured out how to use them in Android.

For example, how would I modify the Hello World program at World program at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html to replace "Hello, Android" with the name of a TV show denoted by an index number (tvshow[0], tvshow[1], etc.)?  Let's name the array tvshow, and the four values in the array are "Route 66", "The Twilight Zone", "Magnum P.I.", and "MASH".

What method(s) can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: The same way you would manipulate arrays in java? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Its the same as in desktop java.  If you have an array that is initialized in a separate Activity that's a different story.  If the array is a field it will be reallocated when the Activity is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) . So all you have to do to add is call the add method and to read you use the get method.

```
ArrayList <String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
//this is how you add the elements you want to.
myArrayList.add("Route 66");
myArrayList.add("The Twitlight Zone");
myArrayList.add("Magnum");
myArrayList.add("P.I.");
myArrayList.add("Mash");
```

and to read the element you want:

```
String tvShow= myArrayList.get(2);
```

The advantage over a normal array (i.e. the one that android developer mentioned) is that you dont need to define an array size and you can add new elements in case the tv shows you have aument by just calling the add method.

Answer (score 0):

well , you are talking about strings , so for an array of strings , you can simply use:

```
String[] tvshow={"Route 66","The Twilight Zone","Magnum", "P.I.", "MASH"} ;
```

for using it , use:

```
String currentTvShow=tvshow[3];
```

for working with strings , read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

strings on java (and on android, since it's based on it)  are not mutable (for various reasons) , so they can't be modified. if you wish to modify such a thing , either use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or an array of chars .